# ReactJS props updating at different speeds in same component

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, redux

I have a Google maps component in a React/Redux app. When you click an item from a list, it passes down an array of coordinates to render as directions from the user's current location. The props are being passed fine through react-redux mapStateToProps. I'm calling a function to generate the the polyline, this is where my problem is. The marker is generated fine inside of render, but the directions do not render until another entry is clicked. Basically it's always one step behind the current markers. So, for 2 stops, I'll have directions from current location to stop 1, but not stop 2. For 3 stops, current location to stop 1 to stop 2 will be generated, but not stop 3.

When I log out the length of the array of stops inside of render I get the expected amount, a length of 1 for 1 stop. I have tried putting the method inside of `componentWillWillReceiveProps` and `componentWillUpdate`, and both methods will log a 0 for 1 stop.

Here's the component, if relevant:

```
const GoogleMapComponent = React.createClass({
  mixin: [PureRenderMixin],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      map: null,
      maps: null,
      color: 0
    }
  },

  componentWillUpdate: function() {
    console.log('LOGS ZERO HERE', this.props.tourList.length)
    if (this.state.maps) {
      this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(this.state.directionsService,     this.state.directionsDisplay, this.props.tourList);
    }
  },

  saveMapReferences: function(map, maps) {
    let directionsDisplay = new maps.DirectionsRenderer({map, polylineOptions: {strokeColor: '#76FF03'}, suppressMarkers: true});
    let directionsService = new maps.DirectionsService();

    this.setState({ map, maps, directionsService, directionsDisplay });
  },

  generateWaypoints: function(coords) {
    return coords.map((coord) => { 
      return { location: new this.state.maps.LatLng(coord.lat, coord.lng) };
    });
  },

  calculateAndDisplayRoute: function(directionsService, directionsDisplay, tourStops) {
    let origin = this.props.userLocation || { lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447 };
    let destination = tourStops[tourStops.length - 1];
    let directions = { origin, destination, travelMode:     this.state.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING };
    if (this.props.tourList.length > 1) {
      directions.waypoints = this.generateWaypoints(tourStops);
    }

    if (tourStops.length > 0) {
      directionsService.route(directions, (response, status) => {
        if (status === this.state.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    } else {
      directionsDisplay.set('directions', null);
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log('LOGS 1 HERE', this.props.tourList.length)
    let markers = this.props.tourList.map((marker, idx) => {
      let loc = marker.prevLoc ? marker.prevLoc : 'your current location.';
      return <Marker className='point' key={idx} image={marker.poster} lat={marker.lat} lng={marker.lng} location={marker.location} price={marker.price} loc={loc} /> 
    });
    let defaultCenter = {lat: 37.762, lng: -122.4394};
    let defaultZoom = 12

    if (this.props.userLocation !== null) {
      return (
        <div className='map'>
          <GoogleMap defaultCenter={defaultCenter} defaultZoom={defaultZoom} yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true} 
                     onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) => {
                        map.setOptions({styles: mapStyles});
                        this.saveMapReferences(map, maps);
                      }} >
            {markers}
          <UserMarker lat={this.props.userLocation.lat} lng=    {this.props.userLocation.lng} />
          </GoogleMap>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className='map'>
        <GoogleMap defaultCenter={defaultCenter} defaultZoom={defaultZoom}              yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true} 
                   onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) => {
                      map.setOptions({styles: mapStyles});
                      this.saveMapReferences(map, maps);
                    }} >
          {markers}
        </GoogleMap>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    tourList: state.sidebar.tourList,
    userLocation: state.home.userLocation
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GoogleMapComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I was not passing `nextProps` to `componentWillUpdate`, so the function was always being called with the old props.

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillUpdate` is called *prior* to `this.props` being updated. Change `componentWillUpdate` as follows:

```
 componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps) {
     console.log('SHOULD LOG ONE HERE', nextProps.tourList.length)
     if (this.state.maps) {
          this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(this.state.directionsService, this.state.directionsDisplay, nextProps.tourList);
     }
  }
```